# If an email sent from php mail() function returns, where is it located in linux?

Tags: php, linux, email, dns, cpanel

I have a page which sends and email to a specific `user@domain.com` via php `mail()` function.

But, the destination domain `domain.com` was not properly  configured on DNS and  none emails were received.

Is there any way to grab all those unsent emails?

Is there a location where unsent emails stay?

I am using Cpanel, but I have root access on the machine, also.

Comment: Depends on your server set up but its likely the server will try and resend `qmail-qread` will show messages in the queue if your using qmail

Comment: mailq on its own will show it in postfix.  failing that they're usually stored in /var/spool/postfix/ in one of the folders in there

Answer (score 0):

If it's running postfix, try looking into the mailq and postcat commands.